# Next dynamic import use

Tags: javascript, next.js, dynamic-import

Should i use in this case dynamic import or not in my Next.js project? (my data is stored in the .json file which is in the same directory as this .js file and it is hosted with the website since it is static)

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const SessionBTN = dynamic(() =>
    import("../../../../../../components/BTN/SessionBTN")
  );

...

{tests[0].tests.map((test, index) => {
            return (
              <SessionBTN
                year={test.year}
              />
            );
          })}

...
```

Comment: test is got like this : import tests from "./tests.json";

Comment: It depends. Is there a reason why you'd want to use a dynamic import for that component?

Comment: what are the reasons to use a dynamic import, I read the docs but didn't get the point of using it ?

Comment: It's used to lazy load/defer loading of React components to help improve initial page load performance. For your specific scenario, and without more details, I don't think it makes much sense to use a dynamic import, though.